# Can someone explain what is happening in this piece of code?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

```
var my_obj = Object.create({}, { 
    getFoo: {
        value: function () { return this.foo; }
    } 
});

my_obj.foo = 1;

console.log(Object.keys(my_obj));
```

This program prints out `foo` as the output. I'm wondering it how. Can I get a proper explanation of what is going on in this program?

Comment: What do you expect as the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) method creates a new object with the specified prototype object and properties:

```
Object.create(proto[, propertiesObject])
```

Using such syntax, by default properties ARE NOT writable, enumerable or configurable. To make it such:

```
var my_obj = Object.create({}, {
    getFoo: {
        value: function () { return this.foo; },
        writable: true,
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    } 
});
```

The property `foo` is enumerable according the way it has been created.

The [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method returns an array of a given object's own **enumerable** properties. That's a reason why you've got `['foo']`.

Comment: thanks @Alex for your response

Answer (score 1):

`Object.keys` returns *enumerable* keys on the object.

Properties defined in `Object.create` are non-enumerable by default (adding `enumerable:true` alongside the `value` would change this).

Properties defined like `my_obj.foo` are enumerable.

Therefore, `Object.keys(my_obj)` only returns `["foo"]`, as that is the only enumerable property on the object.

**Documentation:**

- [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)
- [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: can you explain in detail ? @NiettheDarkAbsol